# custom edit template telerik mvc grid

Tags: templates, grid, edit, telerik-mvc

I use telerik mvc grid and pop up edit template. But I've no idea when I want to custom my edit template. telerik bind all field on my model to it's edit template automatically.

so, how can I change the edit template, such as it's layout, or I want to change textbox to dropdownlist ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an editor template for your model. Brad Wilson has explained this nicely in a [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) (which is part of a [series](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)). There is also a [code library project](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-popup-editor-form.aspx) which shows a working implementation of a custom popup editor form.

Comment: eh wait, is it for telerik mvc ? my question is about grid in telerik mvc :)

Comment: Check the links and you will see :)

Comment: I can't see how this has to do with Telerik MVC grids!

Comment: Of course it does. The Telerik Grid is using Html.EditorFor and Html.EditorForModel to implement the editing. And thanks for the downvote.